# maximum recursion depth exceeded appears when google ndb tasklet tries to update the data

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I was joined to project with a lot of changes frequency, developments have already been done in the project and it has looked like a monolith architecture! sometimes we are using some fields at the ancestors model in a child model to handle some kind of filtering and sorting features (I asked about it before and no solution was introduced to me other than using duplicate fields. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203144/query-on-children-table-and-order-result-of-a-query-by-parents-fields-at-ndb)) therefore we need to update these ancestors fields when a parent was updating, regarding the project is large, I decided to use the *model signals* instead of finding all places and updating the source code to update these fields in the new model, I did this feature with `_post_put_hook` and `_pre_put_hook` signals of `google ndb` [model class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/modelclass).

```
class ParentOne(ndb.Model):
    name_parent_one = ndb.StringProperty()
    ....

   def _post_put_hook(self, future):
       obj = JoinParentNameClasses.query(JoinParentNameClasses.parent_one == self.key).get()
       obj.name_parent_one = self.name_parent_one
       obj.put()

class ParentTwo(ndb.Model):
    name_parent_two = ndb.StringProperty()
    ....

   def _post_put_hook(self, future):
       obj = JoinParentNameClasses.query(JoinParentNameClasses.parent_two == self.key).get()
       obj.name_parent_two = self.name_parent_two
       obj.put()

class JoinParentNameClasses(ndb.Model):
    parent_one = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='ParentOne')
    name_parent_one = ndb.StringProperty()
    parent_two = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='ParentTwo')
    name_parent_two = ndb.StringProperty()
    ... some other fields which was used for API ....
```

**But now bigger problems have emerged:** when someone tries to use `put_multi` or `put_multi_async` of `google ndb`, **NDB** create a lot of `future` objects and sends them for processing with `ndb.tasklet` after that with `.get_result()` gets latest update result, according to `ndb.tasklet` implementation, it's seems like `python coroutines` when we have a lot of rows which is needed to be updated then regarding `_post_put_hook` that updated the children, create a lot of depth and `maximum recursion depth exceeded` appears. How can I solve the problem?

Note. I know about `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)` but this isn't a good solution, I'm looking for *best practice*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `_post_put_hook` seems to be asking for trouble...  Serial puts is a bad idea because it is slow and increases datastore contention.  You might have created an infinite loop as well.

Instead, you want to batch your puts together:

```
class ParentOne(ndb.Model):

    def put_me(self):
        obj = JoinParentNameClasses.query(JoinParentNameClasses.parent_one == self.key).get()
        obj.name_parent_one = self.name_parent_one
        ndb.put_multi([self, obj])
```

You mention that you are already using `ndb.put_multi` which is triggering all the `_post_put_hook` calls.  Instead, write a custom function that

- receives a list of objects
- gets all the relevant parent objects
- puts them all with a single `ndb.put_multi`